# how to make these methods in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, indexing

I'm going through the java book and I'm on chapter 11 but it didn't say anything about how to make these certain method parameters. the top box says java.util.ArrayList:

```
    //+ArrayList()
    public ArrayList(){
     }
    // or is it arrayListE list = new arrayListE();

    //+add(o: E): void

    //+add(index: int, o: E): void

    //+clear(): void
      public void clear(){
       }

    //+contains(o: Object): boolean

    //+isEmpty(): boolean
    public boolean isEmpty(){
    boolean get = true;
     if(contains < 1){
     } else {
         get = false;
    }    
    return get;
   }

  //+get(index: int): E

  //+indexOf(o: Object): int
```

I went through the whole book making programs and then suddenly when it comes to these arraylists these (o: Object) popup on methods (index :int, o: E) and even what type is E e.g +get(index: int): E ... E? please some help here I thought I missed some pages but I re-read the last ten pages and it went from polymorphism to Array List and I was like alright great I get to code a program, but I don't understand what they are asking for or how to code these methods with these symbols. above is as far as I got and the rest when i try different things like for o: E - Object : E i get errors or for (index: int) i'll put exactly that or even index int num, still errors. They didn't explain it in the book these short abbreviations.

Comment: Maybe you didn't try reading anything other than the book. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here are just method signature definitions written in an [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) syntax.

```
+add(index: int, o: E): void
```

`add` is the name of the method and `+` means that it is `public`. `index: int, o: E` are the arguments of the method. `index` is the name of the first agument and `int` its type. Similarly `o` is the name of the second argument. Now `E` is not exactly a type here but refers to the generic type argument of the class. The `ArrayList` can hold objects of arbitrary type as long as it is the same type for every object. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) for more information about generics.
Finally `: void` means that `add` hast the return type `void` i.e. it does not return anything.

If we now write this method in Java it would look like this

```
public void add(int index, E o) {
  // method body
}
```

The other instances in your example work just the same.

The book specifies the signature of the `ArrayList` methods in an abstract way (using UML) and wants you to implement them using concrete Java code. If you need a better description of what these methods are actually supposed to do, you can have a look at the [Javadoc of the ArrayList class.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: when i put the E o within as a parameter it gives me an error saying cannot find symbol: symbol: E, location ArrayList E. how do I make it concrete ? in the book it shows me an example like this:

ArrayList<AConcreteType> list = new ArrayList<>();

and the back and front arrows in place are shaded as well as AConcreteType. am I supposed to put it at the start of my code say within the +ArrayList() or before it?

Comment: @NarinderRSharma You have to declare your class like this `class ArrayList<E> { ...`. This defines `E` to be the generic parameter of the class.

Comment: Then you can create concrete instances like this `ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: now there's just one error left at the end of my starting code i renamed the file and did the class as you said but there is an error at the end: package Chapter11.arrayList;

public class arrayList<E> {
    
arrayList[0] list = new arrayList<E>;

Comment: and i'm guessing my array is now called list also

Comment: What do you want to do with this? `arrayList[0] list = new arrayList<E>;`

Comment: it's asking to make an array list of a generic class with 0 indexes after i am supposed to add indexes myself. but i'm getting an error at the end of that statement at <E> if i even put just brackets <> i get an error or just E.

Comment: Ok you have to leave away the `[0]` and also declare the type of ´list´. Try this: `arrayList<E> list = new arrayList<E>();`. Note you can leave away the `E` in the second brackets.

Comment: oh okay yeah it worked. I will continue tomorrow with this as it's 1 pm i shall go to bed thank you for your help the errors are gone but I have  a feeling I'm not going to know how to add indexes and cities to it. I will re-comply tomorrow or maybe join you in a chat if your available you seem java savey. though my add() methods are as follows so i might be alright: public void add(E o){
        
    } 
    
    public void add(int index, E o){
    
    } ... thnk you for your help if not for you i've been stuck on this for two hours now +

Comment: just to be sure E o, o would be my variable name am i right?

Comment: yes exactly, o is the name, but you are free to chose a different one, the name of the arguments does not matter